# Search all tables in a MS SQL DB for string and return entire row information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been using this bit of code

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
@SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

It does return, the tables and columns that I’m looking for but I am wanting it to return the whole row, more like a “SELECT *, FROM *, WHERE * = ‘string’”, so the output would be a list of tables with all the information in the row

Comment: You can tweak the above SP. Please share the code wat you have did.

Comment: Little confused about what code?

Comment: So you want entire row of the matched column, not single value. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the original Stored Procedure '`SearchAllTables`'. The given SP returns all the matching rows for searching into all the columns with the given search string.

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(256), ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @query = @query + 'SELECT * FROM ' + TableName + ' WHERE ' + LEFT(StuffedCols, LEN(StuffedCols) - 3) + '; ' FROM
(
    SELECT TableName, stuff(
      (
         SELECT ' ( ' + ColumnName + ' like ''%' +  ColumnValue + '%'' ) OR '
         FROM #Results WHERE TableName = t.TableName
         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
      ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
      1, 1, ''
    ) as StuffedCols FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TableName FROM #Results ) t 
) E

Exec( @query)
END
GO
```

Comment: Its only returning "ColumnName" and "ColumnValue", where I am looking for it to return all All Column Names and Values for a Row
More Like a SELECT * FROM

Comment: @DaleAngusBain have u tried to run the above SP? I have run and got exact result. Possible please drop your older SP and create this one as new.

Comment: OK, done that, and it now has an issue returning when mutiples are found

Comment: What is the issue in the result?

Comment: Database 'Phil' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. - Check this error.

Comment: There is no DB called 'Phil' also it kinda odd as the database i'm using this on is called 'MSM'

Comment: @DaleAngusBain please check where the SP is running. I think there is some issue in DB.

Comment: Can you change your answer to have dynamic table variable to store the result, instead of having CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(256), ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)), if you run it again it will complain that table result is already there.